# Trying to call functions in a javascript i.e. JS file from classic ASP

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vbscript

I am trying to call a javascript file from a classic ASP application. The function I'm trying to call is in pow.js and I'm working in tow.asp.

My tow.asp Code looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="pow.js"></script>
Dim MyCall

If MyCall = "" Then
  Response.write("<script type=""text/javascript"">alert(""Inside Call"");</script>")

  Response.Write("<script type=""text/javascript"">$(function () {TestLinks();});</script>")

EndIf
```

My the pow.js file contains the following

```
function TestLinks(){
 alert("Here now");
}
```

When I load the page, I get the alert "Inside Call" and that's all. No response from the TestLinks() javascript function in pow.js

Comment: Do you get any errors in your JavaScript console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

There were 2 errors:

1.) Syntax error with my call. The call from within asp should be:

```
Response.write("<script type=""text/javascript"">TestLinks();</script>")
```

2.) The tag that was referencing the pow.js file should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./pow.js"></script>
```